# How to write a cross-card Java Card applet?

Tags: javacard

Normally, when we write an applet containing a feature that our card not support it, the on-card verifier prevents installing its CAP file.

I want to know if is there any way to write an applet that can install on all cards, but returns an already defined error during run-time for those card that not support one of its features on that method invocation.

More clear, assume that we know all cards support DES cryptography algorithm and some cards support AES as a supplementary algorithm also. Now I want to write an applet that encrypts 8 byte data with AES algorithm if this algorithm is available,or with DES algorithm if AES is not available. Can I do that?

The problem is I think I can't install my applet on those cards that not support AES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mixing two problems:

**1. Algorithm support**

You can easily install your applet, which uses AES, on a card without AES. The absence of AES would cause runtime exceptions in the moment you try to create an instance of the cryptographic object:

```
Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_CBC_NOPAD, false);
```

or

```
KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128);
```

and so on... Note that the exception is an instance of `CryptoException` with `CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM` as the reason code (output of `getReason()` method). That is how your applet can easily decide if the card supports AES. You can surround one of the lines above with try-catch during the installation and downgrade to the more basic algorithm if necessary:

```
Cipher cipher = null;
try {
  //trying AES
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_CBC_NOPAD, false);
} catch (CryptoException e) {
   if (e.getReason() == CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM) {
       //AES missing, so trying DES instead
       cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
   }
}
```

You can use a similar approach to hash functions, signatures etc.

**2. Libraries**

Another problem, which cannot be solved that easily, is the library dependency. If your applet needs to use some proprietary class (as for example `com.nxp.id.jcopx.UtilX` supported by NXP cards), you will not be able to install it on cards without the particular library. The only way for you is to split the problematic code into two packages and make a decision which package to upload based on packages already present on the card.

Comment: Thank you dear vojta. I don't have `getReason()` method for my `Exception` object (i.e. for `e`)! It has only one method named `equals(Object obj): boolean - Object`. Any idea?

Comment: `getReason` is supported by subclasses of `RuntimeException` (e.g. `SystemException`, `CryptoException` etc.) Is your exception an instance of RuntimeException? Try casting it...

Comment: Thanks.Corrected. my `e` object was defined an object of `Exception`. Is there any way to catch all the exceptions (i.e `catch(Exception e)`) and then in the catch body check to see if it is a `CryptoException` or not? if so, how?